# What can I do if I get "overflow encountered in power" to execute sigmoid function?

Tags: python, numpy

When I run these code then I am getting these errors. I couldn't trace anything. I am trying to Implement a logistic regression with Iris data. I am getting problem to obtain accuracy.

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.e ** (-x))

dataset = np.loadtxt("iris.data", delimiter=',', dtype=str)
dataset = dataset[:100]

#array replace element
dataset = np.where(dataset == 'Iris-setosa', 1, dataset)
dataset = np.where(dataset == 'Iris-versicolor', -1, dataset)

#data type casting
m = dataset.astype(float)

#suffle
np.random.shuffle(m)

#select the first 30 samples for test (70 samples are training data).
testX = m[:30]
testY = m[:30,-1]


trainX = m[30:100]
trainY = m[30:100,-1]

#initialization
w = np.zeros(5)
b = 0
#learning rate
lr = 0.05

# GD
for i in range(1000):
    w_diff = np.dot(np.transpose(trainY - sigmoid(np.dot(trainX, w))), trainX)
    w = w + lr * w_diff

print("w: ", w)
# test
print(sum(np.round(sigmoid(np.dot(testX, w))) == testY)/np.size(testY))
```

The error is following:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  return 1 / (1 + np.e ** (-x))
w:  [ -658.80023765  1572.88332431 -4295.61240946 -1716.37312787
  3374.58205697]
0.03333333333333333
```

Comment: I'd switch your sigmoid function to use numpy's `np.exp()` function rather than the `np.e **` operation. If you change to this, does the error persist?

Comment: ...even better, use `scipy.special.expit`, as suggested in @user2640045's answer.  It is written to avoid the potential overflow of the "naive" implementation(s).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for large negative numbers x `np.e**(-x)` and `np.exp(-x)` give you giant positive numbers.

Running

```
def sigmoid(x): return 1 / (1 + np.e ** (-x))
sigmoid(-800)
```

gives the same error you get.

While

```
from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid
sigmoid(-800)
```

works just fine and gives you the same values. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html.

Comment: I am using from scipy.special import expit as sigmoid but still it is giving my accuracy 0.0

Comment: @SMSarwar That most likely has nothing to do with the sigmoid. So I suggest you ask a new question.